# mysqli echo user data

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this php for database connection and I am trying to echo user data (username of the loggedin user) in my home.php

```
    <?php

  session_start();

$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password="browser"; // Mysql password
$db_name="test"; // Database name
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
$con = mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysqli_select_db($con,"test") or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $myusername);
$mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysqli_query($con, $sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
$_SESSION['username']= "username";
$_SESSION['password']= "password";
header("location:home.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

Now on the home.php I want to echo the username of the logged in user

```
 <?php
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['username']= "username"){
header("location:main_login.php");
}
?>

<html>
<body>
<h1>Logged in Successful</h1>
as 

<?php echo $data['username']; ?>!

</body>
</html>
```

how do i call this function?

Comment: why are you using `$data` when you stored everything into the session? what's wrong with `echo $_SESSION['username']`?

Comment: for some reason the <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?> just echoes the word "username" not the users username @user3487121

Comment: Take a look at `$_SESSION['username'] = "username"`. Why else should it be anything BUT `username`?

Comment: I changed that, well I still couldn't get it to work. I created a user in data base with username "Doe". I felt if I echoed `<?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?>`. it would print "Doe" and not the word "username". That's exactly what I am trying to achieve

Comment: you run your query, you check the number of rows, but you never actually FETCH any results. you're just assigning some hardcoded strings to the session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$data` undeclared variable has no sense here.

You must change this line: `<?php echo $data['username']; ?>`

To: `<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>`

Comment: for some reason the <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?> just echoes the word "username" not the users username

Comment: your are assigning it here: `$_SESSION['username']= "username";`

Comment: In fact, you should change these 2 lines: `$_SESSION['username']= $myusername;
$_SESSION['password']= $mypassword;`

Comment: I changed that, well I still couldn't get it to work. I created a user in data base with username "Doe". I felt if I echoed <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?> it would print "Doe" and not the word "username". That's exactly what I am trying to achieve

Comment: You have a typo here (in home.php): `if(!$_SESSION['username'] = "username")` In order to compare you must use `==`

Answer (score 0):

Just `echo $_SESSION['username']`, no need to do anything else.

Answer (score 0):

@user3487121

As you have already store user data in to session so you need to write below code to print the user name.

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your second code to:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!($_SESSION['username'] == "username")){
        header("location:main_login.php");
}
?>

<html>
<body>
<h1>Logged in Successful</h1>
as 

<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>!

</body>
</html>
```

Pay attention on first if `if(!$_SESSION['username'] == "username"){`.

You use operator = to check if value in session equivalently to 'username', but for this purpose you need to use ==.

[Comparsion operators(manual)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

[All operators(manual)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php)